# Getting a error when implement leaderboard and achievement in Android

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have a issue when using Game Service of Google. I use Leaderboard and Achievement in my game. But when I run direct from PC to Device, all things is normal.

But when I export apk file and upload it on Goole Play, I got a issue in below image.

[image]

Comment: Try reading the logcat, if it exists?

Comment: @cricket_007 Nothing show in logcat. Thank you

Comment: Then it's kinda hard to help you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the given [quality checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) which is presented with minimum requirements, best practices, and good-to-have enhancements to deliver the best possible product to your players.

In addition to that, since nothing shows in logcat, you may also try going through these references and/or tutorial:

- [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)
- [Google Play Game Services: Leaderboards](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700)